# How to Enable diagnostic logs for Windows Azure VMRoles created using Azure Portal

Tags: java, windows, azure, diagnostics, azure-cloud-services

I have created Virtual Machine directly on Azure Portal, Now i am trying to enable the Diagnostic logs for monitoring the CPU Usage. But i am not able to see the configure Tab in Cloud Service. Where as i observed that if i deploy the VM using Visual Studio then it shows the tag to configure cloud service and diagnostic logs.

I have also tried to get the service definition and cloud service configuration using REST API "Get Package", http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj154121.aspx but it failed saying that no service definition exits.

How can i enable Diagnostic logs or is there any way to get the CPU Usage and other matrics using REST API or Java API?

Comment: is that an azure vm in IaaS?

Comment: Yes, I want to get the CPU Usage of VM running in Azure IaaS.

Comment: I am looking for any REST API or Java API to get the numbers, i found that if i can enable Diagnostic logs then i can use blob api to query table and get the details from blob table WADPerformanceCountersTable.

Comment: don't think there are standard options given similar to PaaS. You can look at third party monitoring tools like Azurewatch https://www.paraleap.com/ and Newrelic agent http://newrelic.com/